# Creating an array of objects based on filename data

Tags: javascript

I am writing JavaScript code for a nodeJS server to recursively get filenames within a directory and store in an array. From there, based on the filenames and directory locations, create objects based on said data and store in a new array.

Here are some examples of what the filenames look like:

```
var files = [
  'foo001/foo001.jpg',
  'foo001/foo001_blue10_sat22.jpg',
  'bar030/bar030.jpg',
  'bar030/bar030_red31_dpq40_grey10.jpg',
  'baz201/baz201.jpg',
  'baz201/baz201_yellow45.jpg'
];
```

The new array would look like:

```
var fileObjects = [
  {key: 'foo001/foo001.jpg'},
  {key: 'foo001/foo001_blue10_sat22.jpg', blue: 10, sat: 22},
  {key: 'bar030/bar030.jpg'},
  {key: 'bar030/bar030_red31_dpq40_grey10.jpg', red: 31, dpq: 40, grey: 10},
  {key: 'baz201/baz201.jpg'},
  {key: 'baz201/baz201_yellow45.jpg', yellow: 45}
];
```

What is the best way to approach this problem? Is this strictly a regex problem? Or are there particular JS libraries that can help handle this that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

If filenames are consistent, using regex should be enough.

My approach will be:

- use `array.map()` with callback
- callback should use `string.indexOf()` to find 'key' value
- callback should `string.split()` filename (without the 'key') with delimiter '_' and parse splitted parts to extract properties and their respective values